# Disable scrolling for 0.5 seconds after the user scrolls once in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a resizing header with `heigth:100%`. I need to disable scrolling for *0.5 seconds* after the user scrolls once. Is there any way to do that in JavaScript ?

**Here is my code:**

```
<script>
    function init() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 50,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(header,"smaller");         
            } else {
                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                    classie.remove(header,"smaller");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = init();
</script>
```

Comment: I would encourage you not to disable scrolling, ever. Why? The user may think that his mouse is broken, then punch his computer then... in summary it's a bad user experience to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the script below, if the user starts scrolling the function will be triggered and it will disable scrolling after 0.5 seconds.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                var header = document.getElementById("header");
                header.style.overflow = "hidden";
            }, 500 /* miliseconds */);
    };
</script>
```

If you want to disable scrolling for 0.5s after the user starts scrolling you can use this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
            var header = document.getElementById("header");
            header.style.overflow = "hidden";
            setTimeout(function() {
                header.style.overflow = "auto";
            }, 500 /* miliseconds */);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the accepted answer to this question:  [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)  To make this disabling temporary, one strategy would be to set the event handlers mentioned in the answer, then use `setTimeout` with a duration of 500 milliseconds.  The callback function within your `setTimeout` could then remove the event handlers.  Thus, after a delay, browser behavior would return to normal.